# How to make a Menu not close when a MenuItem's click event is invoked (Electron)

Tags: javascript, electron

I have a simple Menu on a Tray application for electron.

I have a `click` option on my MenuItem and every time I click the menu item the menu closes. What can I do to make it stay?

I've read through this documentation: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/menu-item but can't seem to find the answer.

Supposedly the third argument to the click is a `KeyboardEvent` which extends `Event` which has a `preventDefault` on it, but if I try to invoke `click: (item, menu, e) => { e.preventDefault(); }` it throws an error saying `e.preventDefault` is not a function.

Hopefully i'm missing something simple, thanks in advance!

Here's what my menu looks like:

```
Menu.buildFromTemplate([
        {
            label: 'pls dont close',
            click: (menuItem, window, e) => {
               e.preventDefault();
            }
        },
        {
            label: 'Quit',
            click: app.quit
        }
    ])
```

Comment: I copied your example, and it's working for me. I have two buttons in menu. One with "pls don't close", and another with "Quit" label. When i click first - nothing is happened, second - app quit. If i remove preventDefault, app still does not close, because there is no logic for close by clicking at this button. I'm having  8.0.3 electron version and ubuntu. Do you see your labels and which platform you are running on?

Comment: Vladimir that’s interesting. I’ll have to play around with it to see why it’s happening to me and not to you, then. Some more context is that the application is a System Tray app only. Maybe that affects it? I’m on a PC as well.

Comment: Hey I have the same problem.. did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/3637) on Electron's Github repo, the behavior isn't supported.